# Как сделать проверку поставил ли юзер лайк в instagram

Tags: php, instagram, instagram-api

Вопрос, как можно проверить лайк под постом. Я беру у юзера его логин перед тем, как направить его на пост. Вывожу по api instagram, только 1000 лайков из-за лимита. Но когда делаю условия, чтобы вывести больше. Instagram блокирует меня. Как избежать блокировки аккаунта, но получать список лайков и найти такого самого юзера, который поставил лайк?

Comment: поверить ему на слово, один фиг потом может снять его.

Comment: Как-то не хочется верить на слово))

Answer (score 0):

Когда перебираешь в цикле сделать задержку с помощью `sleep(second)`, в аргументах указываешь время в секундах, пример `sleep(3)` - задержка на три секунд

Comment: У меня стоит задержка sleep(5), но выборка лайков всегда одна и та же (может поменяться до 3 пользователей из 1000).